# $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\;\land\;\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=f(0)$. Prove $f(x)$ is continuous at all $a$. (Question about a particular step)

Tags: limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta, substitution

### **Let $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\;\text{and}\;\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=f(0)$. Prove $f(x)$ is continuous at all $a$.**

I want to know if the following substitution I´ve done is a valid step of the proof. I have already seen the other questions related to the problem but my concern is on the specific step.

---

*($f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ are implied by de definition of $f(x)$ and will be taken for granted.)*

$$0<|u-0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(u)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$$
$$0<|u|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(u)|<\varepsilon$$

> **let $u=x-a$** *

$$0<|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x-a)|<\varepsilon$$
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$
$\square$

---

Translated to "$\lim$" notation:

$$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}f(u)=0$$

> **let $u=x-a$** *

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x-a)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)-f(a)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$$
$\square$

---

Is the step next to "*" a valid one?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: That's a pretty standard implication of the rule of substitution in limits. Whatever happens with $f(x) $ as $x\to 0$, the same happens with $f(x-a) $ as $x\to a$.